# Import bootstrap on react with webpack

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, webpack, css-loader

I try to import bootstrap on my react project but it doesn't works. First, I had this error

```
ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module parse failed: C:\wamp\www\project\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css\bootstrap.css Line 9: Unexpected token :
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| html
| {
|     font-family: sans-serif;
|
|         -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
 @ ./src/client/app/index.jsx 11:0-43
```

So I installed css-loader with npm updated my webpack.config.js like this :

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var path = require('path');

var BUILD_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/public');
var APP_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/client/app');

var config = {
  entry: APP_DIR + '/index.jsx',
  output: {
    path: BUILD_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module : {
    loaders : [
      {
        test : /\.jsx?/,
        include : APP_DIR,
        loader : 'babel'
      },
      { test: /\.(woff|woff2)(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file' },
      { test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file' },
      { test: /\.eot(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file'},
      { test: /\.svg(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/, loader: 'file' },
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        loader: 'style!css!less'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/, // Only .css files
        loader: 'css-loader'
      }
    ]
  }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Now, I got this error message :

```
ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'file' in C:\wamp\www\project\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css
 @ ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 6:4886-4938 6:4963-5015

ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'file' in C:\wamp\www\project\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css
 @ ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 6:5065-5119

ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'file' in C:\wamp\www\project\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css
 @ ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 6:5150-5203

ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'file' in C:\wamp\www\project\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css
 @ ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 6:5233-5285

ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'file' in C:\wamp\www\project\node_modules\bootstrap\dist\css
 @ ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css 6:5319-5371
```

I don't understand how to configure correctly webpack.config.js.

Anyone have an answer to my problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Loading `CSS` requires the `css-loader` and the `style-loader`. They have two different jobs. The `css-loader` will go through the `CSS` file and find `url()` expressions and resolve them. The `style-loader` will insert the raw css into a style tag on your page.
 so you need both of them.
Use this

```
{
      test: /\.css$/, // Only .css files
      loader: 'style!css' // Run both loaders
}
```

You also need to install them as dependency in your package.json file. You can do that using (if have not done)

```
npm install css-loader style-loader --save
```